# Possible to edit icons in headers of docking manager using syncfusion

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I am wondering if it is possible to edit the icons in the headers of a docking manager? I can edit the background colour of the docking manager but how do you make the text bold, and the icons colour black I'm using the office 2010 silver theme as the colours for the headers are what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can edit the text and icons in the header by applying our own template to the headers using **HeaderTemplate** attached property. We have prepared a sample for the same kindly download it from the following link:

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/147492/ze/DockingManager_FloatWindowTemplate558754838

Regards,
Jessie

Comment: Thanks Jessie, that was perfect and exactly what I needed :)